# Retrieving a row and column from Access Database

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

In my project are two matrices using Microsoft Access database, sourced from two different tables (for example `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`). I need to retrieve a row and a column from that database.

Selecting `COL1` from one table means selecting a corresponding row from the other.

I would like to retrieve `COL1` and the corresponding row at the same time.

How is this possible using SQL and a JDBC call?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you not sure how to use joins or how to retrieve data?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Post examples and source code if you are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with two separate tables of the same database you will need one `Connection` and a `Statement` and a `ResultSet` for each database table.

Since you do not clarify how you have stored your matrix data in the database i can not give you more details here. But, whatever you do, in order to access the contents of the first matrix from the database table you will have to replicate for the second. Just change the table name in your SQL select.

However it will not happen "at the same time", one query will follow the other.

Comment: Why do you need a result set from each table? If the tables have a column (field) in common, why not use a JOIN, Access is happy with INNER, LEFT and RIGHT joins.

Comment: Access is in general not very happy... :-) but sure, he could join, specially if the matrices are not huge.

Comment: Especially if they are huge, otherwise it will take forever to go through row by row.

Comment: The trouble is that we do not know how the tables are designed. We just guess. Anyway, it an interesting issue to compare a join and double ResultSets. This join is between identically structured tables of the same size and order.